# Cordova Parse Plugin not working

Tags: android, cordova, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I am facing issue with implementing [Avivais Phonegap-Plugin-parse](https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin) in my ionic project. Below are the steps I followed.

**Issue**

I always get `Reference Error: parsePlugin not defined`.

**Steps followed**

a. Run this command in Ionic project directory.

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/benjie/phonegap-parse-plugin`

b. Add android platform. `ionic platform add android`

c. in `www/js/app.js` add this code.

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
    try{
        parsePlugin.initialize('XXX', 'YYY', function() {
            alert('success');
        }, function(e) {
            alert('error');
        });

    }catch(err){
        alert('Parse Error '+err.message); //this gets executed all time
    }
  });
})
```

**Note**

a. The plugin is installed and shows in `plugins/org.apache.cordova.core.parseplugin`

b. The `platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml` has

```
<feature name="ParsePlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.core.ParsePlugin" />
 </feature>
```

c. The `index.html` has `<script src="cordova.js"></script>`

d. `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.ionicframework.ecopulse420832" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Can anyone please tell me what am I missing here to add or check?

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve this issue? Or do you need help with it?

Comment: @thanks for reply M O H. fortunately I have resolved this issue.. just out of curiosity .. do you know about parse.com channel subscription?

Comment: Well I am working on a project right now that uses the above plugin. My app is based on ionic angular require and parse. I have managed to get it working well. I have developed an idea regarding channel subscription though i will not be using the channel approach, but the advanced querying approach documented in parse.

Comment: Hey, how did you solve this problem? I am facing exactly the same issue and some pointers from you might save some hours of debugging.

Comment: hi @GunjanKarun , i had a silly mistake.. for another JS lib the script tag above `cordova.js` was not closed and so js was conflicting. Ensure you have cordova.js import and second all other imports are working.